# How do you go about sketching any function of the form $\cos(cx^n)$ or $\sin(cx^n)$

Tags: calculus

How do you go about sketching any function of the form $\cos(cx^n)$ or $\sin(cx^n)$  where $c$ is a constant? What are the steps needed? I'm aware of the basic graphs of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, but the exponent here is throwing me off. What effect does $n$ have, if it is even? or odd?

Comment: Hints: (1) The transformation is non-linear, so the oscillations will become more and more compressed with increasing $ \ \vert x \vert \ $ ; (2) the composition of an odd function on an odd function is odd; the other combinations of symmetries (odd on even, even on odd, even on even) are even. The constant multiplier has the usual effect on horizontal "stretches/compressions".

Comment: @RecklessReckoner so, for example if my function is $cos(x^2)$ then my first derivative is $-2xsin(x^2)$ if I set that to zero I can arrive at $sin(x^2)$ and I know the zeros of $sin(x)$ are at every $n \pi$ , so if he zeros of $sin(x)$ happen at intervals of $n \pi$ is it a good assumption to just take the square root of that and say the zeros of $sin(x^2)$ are at intervals $ {\sqrt n \sqrt\pi}$ ?

Comment: I presume you're asking about the locations of the extrema. The trigonometric equations should invert without complication: for your example you would have $ \ x \ = \ \pm \sqrt{k \ \pi} \ $, again by symmetry.   The locations would be found analogously for other powers, and are located symmetrically for even or odd integer exponents. The constant multiplier $ \ c \ $ can be brought in directly if its positive; for $ \ c \ < \ 0 \ $ , apply the symmetry properties of the sine and cosine functions _first_, so you don't have to contend with even roots of " $  -c \ $ " .

Answer (score 1):

For $-1<=x<=1$, your shouldn't have much trouble since $x^n\rightarrow 0$  as $n$ grows. But outside this interval, you'll have a "sine-looking"  graph where the distance between zeros becomes smaller and smaller as either $n$ or $x$ grow. In fact, whatever graph method you use, pen and paper, graphing calculator or computer, for sufficiently large $n$ or small $x<-1$, or large $x>1$, your graph will look like a filled-in rectangle.

Comment: Thank you -- I'd overlooked that the power function would acts like a "horizontal stretch" for $ \ \vert x \vert \ < \ 1 \  $ . (I think you want absolute-value brackets in your last sentence.)

Comment: I've changed $x<1$ to $x<-1$